# IE external css not items in webpage

Tags: html, css

okay so i have a external css page for IE.

```
h1 {
font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
font-size: 40px;
position: absolute;
top:150px;
left: 200px;
color:#FC3B3B;
}

h2 {
font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left: -100px;
color: black;
}
h3 {
font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
position: absolute;
top:300px;
left: 400px;
}
image2 {
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left: 100px;
}
box1 {
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
background-color:  #FC3B3B;
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left: 0px;
}
p {
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left: 0px;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: arial;
color: #585858;
}
```

however, all i can change is the color in h1. i can not change the position in h1. regarding the rest of the items i can not change anything. i need to change the positioning of items as it is very off in IE. the webpage is fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Answer (score 1):

Chances are good that they are overwritten either by a more specific selector or one that appears after that CSS is loaded.

The easiest fix is using `!important`:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 150px !important;
    left: 200px !important;
    color: #FC3B3B;
}
```

Note: You do not need to repeat everything if you have it somewhere else.

There are also some other mistakes in your CSS: `image2` and `box1` aren't valid tags. You most likely wanted `.image2` and `.box1` (or `#image2` in case of IDs being used).

Comment: thanks this has allowed me to move things. however its had some wierd effect on my text in that it stacks words on top of each other

Comment: Well, absolutely-positioned elements are taken outside of the regular layout flow...

Comment: what would i change it to to stop this from happening?

Comment: Well.. not using `absolute` but `relative` positioning could do the job. Hard to say without seeing your HTML code. Consider asking a new question - and don't forgot the jsfiddle containing the HTML+CSS where the issue occurs. Obviously in a way that we don't have to use IE to test it.

Comment: i changed to relative but no effect. interestly i had the top item as absolute and the next item as relative and this text went normal. i have no clue what a jsfiddle is! is there a way you can chat me to help?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21597/discussion-between-louismoore18-and-thiefmaster)

Comment: Sorry, don't have time for that. Feel free to join one of the generic chatrooms (the [javascript room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) usually has people who are also good with html/css)